# Writing a string to a file gives output with weird characters in assembly

Tags: assembly, dos, x86-16, 16-bit

I am trying to save my string to a file in assembly but it gives me this weird output with "ver 2.40 (all kinds of special characters)"

This is what I do:

```
mov ah,09
mov dx,200
int 21
int 20

e 200 "Test$"
n test.com
r cx
:0009
w
q
```

It saves it succesfully and it also runs fine when I don't exit the program and use "g" but when I "q" and try to run test.com it gives me the output I mentioned.

Comment: Just out of interest: what assembler is this?

Comment: Windows 3.1 it's a school excersise

Comment: Windows 3.1 is an operating system, not an assembler. But thanks for the hint anyway, will figure it out.

Comment: Yea well we had to install windows 3.1 and on start-up dos just starts so I don't know the specific version or anything

Comment: Only the opcode was written into the file, but not the string placed at the address hex 0200.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I presume you're using DEBUG.EXE.

After `e 200 "Test$"` do a `d 200`. You see the memory dump beginning at offset 200. This looks like:

```
16C7:0200  54 65 73 74 24 00 00 00-00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   Test$...........
16C7:0210  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00-00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ................
16C7:0220  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00-00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ................
16C7:0230  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00-00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ................
16C7:0240  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00-00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ................
16C7:0250  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00-00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ................
16C7:0260  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00-00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ................
16C7:0270  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00-00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ................
```

Now count the offset up until you reach the `24`: 200, 201, 202, 203, 204 - You want to store the memory from offset 100h until 204h, this are 105h bytes (204h-100h+1).

This value is to be stored in `CX`:

```
r cx
:0105
```

With `w` you write `CX` bytes.

Comment: Thanks this works! It always has to be +1 from the 24 right?

Comment: @SinanSamet: Yes. If you want to store one byte beginning at 100h you have to calculate (100h - 100h + 1). BTW: Google for "off by one error".

Comment: Debug manual: http://www.armory.com/~rstevew/Public/Tutor/Debug/debug-manual.html

Answer (score 1):

`int 20` is not the problemm I don't think. 9 in `cx` is not enough to write code at 100 (presumably) and string at 200. I think you want `w 100` also. If this is not DEBUG, forgive me.

Answer (score 0):

My DOS book says of `int 20h`

> This was the standard way to terminate DOS programs on DOS V1. With the
>   introduction of DOS functions `4Ch` and `31h` this is no longer the
>   recommended way to terminate a program unless it must maintain
>   compatibility with DOS V1 systems.

I suggest you use `int 21h` function `AH = 4Ch` with `AL` set to a return code.

Comment: It's a little unclear for me I'm really just a beginner with this trying to understand it

Comment: @SinanSamet In short: it's deprecated. Use WeatherVane's suggestion instead.

Comment: This will be true under Windows 3.1.

Comment: We can also terminate a DOS based COM-programm with a "ret" instruction, if we do not corrupt the stack and the code segment. Because DOS place the instruction of an "int 20h" at the top of the PSP and it pushes a zero word to the stack just before it let the programm execute. If we execute at last the "ret" instruction, then the cpu return to the address of zero and continue executing the instruction of the "int 20h" inside of the PSP for terminating our programm.